# Image blending modes for HDR images

Tags: image-processing, graphics, hdrimages, visual-effects

The blending modes Screen, Color Dodge, Soft Light, etc.
like in Photoshop, each have their own math that works
for range 0-1. I wonder how do these blend modes work
for HDR images?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with photoshop and it's filter but here is a general explanation of the math behind HDR filters.

Suppose you have 3 images (low light, medium and over exposed). You want to average those images but (I1+I2+I3)/3 is a stupid way. You want to give a higher weight to the image that captures more information in a given area.
So basically you average the images with a weight factor and there are different types of algorithms to calculate the weights. Here are few:

1. The simplest one is using STD (standard deviation). In each pixel, in each image calculate standard deviation of its 9 neighbours. Use std as weight: 
   HDR pixel(i,j) = I1(i,j)*stdI1(i,j) + I2(i,j)*stdI2(i,j) + I3(i,j)*stdI3(i,j).
   Why std is used? since when std is high it means a high variation in pixels intencity which means more information was captured by the image.
2. Instead of STD you can use entropy filter, edge detection or any other which represents how much information is encoded around the given pixel
3. There are also slower but better ways to do HDR. Usually it is done with some kind of wavelet transformation. For example Furier transform. Each image is converted to furier space (coefficients of the frequencies and than the for each frequency, the maximal coefficient of 3 images is taken).
4. You can even combine the method of std filter and wavelet transforms. For example break the image to different frequencies, smooth the lower frequencies and take a stupid average  (I1+I2+I3)/3, but with high frequencies use less smoothing and using std weighted average. The action of smoothing more lower frequencies is called 'blending'. It heavily  used when stitching 2 images of different light exposure to a panorama.
   Look at this image: http://magazine.magix.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Panorama-3.jpg
   You can clearly see that the sky gets different color on each image but since sky is a very low frequency (almost no information and no small object) it is heavily smoothed and averaged, thus allowing a gentle stitching.

Hope that answers your question